# Time field for form API

Tags: 8, forms

When I use datetime field without date I get the message below. I want to provide a field for time only.

[image: Error message]

This code is correct but still has the problem of the time field.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\ets\Form\Sejours_sportifs;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup;
use Drupal\Core\Database\Database;
use Drupal\Core\Url;
use Drupal\file\Entity\File;

/**
 * Class SejourSportif.
 */
class SejourSportif extends FormBase {
  public $liste = array();

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'sejour_sportif';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $form['#cache'] = ['max-age' => 0];

    $this->connection = Database::getConnection();
    $connection = Database::getConnection();
    $req = "SELECT id, name FROM details_types_sejours_field_data;";
    $reponse = $connection->query($req);
    $results = $reponse->fetchAll();
    $this->liste += [
          '0' => t('Choose'),
    ];
    foreach ($results as $result){
      $this->liste += [
          $result->id => $result->name,
      ];
    }
    $header = array();
    $header['journee'] = $this->t('Stays days');
    $header['matin'] = $this->t('Morning');
    $header['soir'] = $this->t('Evening');
    $header['observations'] = $this->t('Comments');
    $header['operation'] = $this->t('Action');

    $promoted_items = array();
    $number_promoted = $form_state->getValue('number_promoted', count($promoted_items));
    $removed = $form_state->getValue('removed_promoted', []);

    $form['number_promoted'] = [
      '#type' => 'value',
      '#value' => $number_promoted,
    ];
    $form['removed'] = [
      '#type' => 'value',
      '#value' => $removed,
    ];
    $form['promoted'] = array(
      '#type' => 'table',
      '#header' => $header,
      '#title' => t("Days number"),
      '#tree' => TRUE,
    );
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $number_promoted; $i++) {
      $form['#cache'] = ['max-age' => 0];
      $item = array_shift($promoted_items);
      if (in_array($i, $removed)) {continue;}
      $form['promoted-container'] = [
        '#type' => 'container',
        '#title' => t("Day number #@i", ['@i' => $i]),
      ];

      // Journée

      $form['promoted'][$i] = [
        'journee' => array(
          '#type' => 'date',
          '#title' => $this->t('Stays'),
          //'#default_value' => $item['title'],
        ),

        // Matin

        'matin' => array(
          array(
            '#type' => 'datetime',
            '#title' => $this->t("Start hour"),
            '#date_date_element' => 'none', // hide date element 
            '#date_time_element' => 'time', // you can use text element here as well 
            '#date_time_format' => 'H:i',
            '#default_value' => '00:00',
          ),
          array(
            '#type' => 'datetime',
            '#title' => $this->t("End hour"),
            //'#default_value' => $item['title'],
            '#date_date_element' => 'none', // hide date element 
            '#date_time_element' => 'time', // you can use text element here as well 
            '#date_time_format' => 'H:i',
            '#default_value' => '00:00',
          ),
          array(
            '#type' => 'select',
            '#default_value' => 'Choose',
            '#options' => $this->liste,
            '#title' => $this->t('Requested service:'),
          )
        ),

        // Soir

        'soir'=>array(
          array(
            '#type' => 'datetime',
            '#title' => $this->t("Start hour"),
            //'#default_value' => $item['title'],
            '#date_date_element' => 'none', // hide date element 
            '#date_time_element' => 'time', // you can use text element here as well 
            '#date_time_format' => 'H:i',
            '#default_value' => '00:00',
          ),
          array(
            '#type' => 'datetime',
            '#title' => $this->t("End hour"),
            //'#default_value' => $item['title'],
            '#date_date_element' => 'none', // hide date element 
            '#date_time_element' => 'time', // you can use text element here as well 
            '#date_time_format' => 'H:i',
            '#default_value' => '00:00',
          ),
          array(
            '#type' => 'select',
            '#default_value' => 'Choose',
            '#options' => $this->liste,
            '#title' => $this->t('Requested service:'),
          )
        ),

        // Observations

        'observations' => array(
          '#type' => 'textarea',
          '#title' => $this->t('Comments:'),
          '#cols' => '20',
          '#rows' => '5',
        ),
      ];

      // Boutons

      $form['promoted'][$i]['remove_' . $i] = [
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t("Delete stays #@i", ['@i' => $i]),
        '#submit' => ['::removeItem'],
        '#attributes' => [
          'class' => ['button--danger'],
          'data-toRemove' => $i,
        ],
      ];
    }

    $form['#cache'] = ['max-age' => 0];
    $form['promoted-container'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Add new stays'),
      '#submit' => ['::addPromotedItem'],
    ];

    return $form;
  }


  public function addPromotedItem(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['#cache'] = ['max-age' => 0];

    $form_state->setValue('number_promoted', $form_state->getValue('number_promoted') + 1);
    $form_state->setRebuild();
  }

  public function removeItem(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    //$form['#cache'] = ['max-age' => 0];

    /*$removed[] = $form_state->getTriggeringElement()['#attributes']['data-toRemove'];

    if(count($promoted)>1){
      // Find the key of the item we need to remove
      $removed = array_search($data-toRemove, 'promoted');

      // Remove our triggered element
      unset($[$key_to_remove]);

      // Rebuild the field deltas values
      $form_state->set('field_froid_ferme', $field_livraisons_array);

      // Rebuild the form
      $form_state->setRebuild();
    }else{
    */


    $removed = $form_state->getValue('removed_promoted');
    $removed[] = $form_state->getTriggeringElement()['#attributes']['data-toRemove'];
    $form_state->setValue('removed_promoted', $removed);
    unset($removed[count($removed)-1]);
    $form_state->setValue('number_promoted', $form_state->getValue('number_promoted') - 1);
    //$form_state->setValue('removed_promoted', $removed);
    $form_state->setRebuild();
    $form_state->setValue('removed_promoted', $removed);
  }



  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    //parent::validateForm($form, $form_state);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // Display result.
    /*foreach ($form_state->getValues() as $key => $value) {
      //drupal_set_message($key . ': ' . $value);
    }
    */
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you share how you removed the date field from the datetime field? Maybe answer lies in there.

Comment: $form['time_container']['time'] = [
  '#type' => 'datetime',
  '#title' => $this->t('Time'),
  '#size' => 20,
  '#date_date_element' => 'none', // hide date element 
  '#date_time_element' => 'time', // you can use text element here as well 
  '#date_time_format' => 'H:i'
];

Comment: I added the datetime field using the UI and then in the code I hid the #date_date_element as you are doing in your code. And it's working fine and not showing any error. However on content display it was showing the full datetime which I corrected by using the datetime custom field formatter.

Comment: There is new module to provide you time_field " https://www.drupal.org/project/time_field "

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your #default_value is undefined. I suggest you add the default value for the field too. Like this -

```
$form['time_container']['time'] = [
  '#type' => 'datetime',
  '#title' => $this->t('Time'),
  '#size' => 20,
  '#date_date_element' => 'none', // hide date element
  '#date_time_element' => 'time', // you can use text element here as well
  '#date_time_format' => 'H:i',
  '#default_value' => '00:00',
 ];
```

Comment: when I add new line in my form, only the values in time fields are missed !!!

Comment: New line like <br> in the #markup or something else. Can you update the question with the code you are using for the form?